# Extracting Char Array From getline, Without the Use of String

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing, char, text-extraction

So I want to getline from a text file, and extract the first word in each line and save in a char array "op". I'm having trouble dealing with the spaces that come before the first word.. The first line in the text is "awesome sauce", the second is "yes", the third is "cool", and the fourth is "  yeah ok". It's having trouble dealing with the spaces before the word yeah.

infile.open("vec.txt");

```
//define line pointer

char* line=new char[100];   
char other[100];
char op[100]; 
int numofLines = 0; 
int k = 0; 
bool wordStart = false; 

//get line
while (infile.getline(other,100))
{
    int numofChar = k; 
    int numofOpChar = 0; 
    int r = 0; 
    int p = 0; 

    while (other[k] == ' ')
    {
        while (other[k] != ' ')
        {
            wordStart = true; 
        }
        k++; 
        cout << k << endl; 
    }

    if (wordStart = true)
    {
        do
        {
            op[numofOpChar] = other[numofChar]; 
            numofChar++; 
            numofOpChar++; 

        }
        while (other[numofChar] != ' '); 

        if (op[numofChar] != ' ')
        {
            cout << op << endl; 
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Do you want to concatenate all first words in the file to one character array op?

Comment: No, I want the opcode array to contain the first word each time, at each instance.

Comment: diud you step through the code with a debugger? Where does it go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly what you need is the following. I used `std::stringstream` instead of a file for simplicity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    const char text[] = "awesome sauce\n" "yes\n" "cool\n" " yeah ok";
    char line[N];
    char op[N];
    size_t pos = 0;

    std::istringstream is( text );

    while ( is >> op )
    {
        is.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
        std::cout << op << std::endl;
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
awesome
yes
cool
yeah
```

Answer (score 0):

u should use k to start the string extraction

```
numofchar = k;
if (wordStart = true)
{
    do
    {
        op[numofOpChar] = other[numofChar];
```